# Find any match in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array of objects in Javascript, I need to check that the value is in that object to return the id.
I am using the `some()` function but it only works if it matches the first object

This is the array:

```
const testObj = [
  {id: 1, nombre: "Juan"},
  {id: 2, nombre: "María"},
  {id: 3, nombre: "Pedro"}
];
```

This is what I do:

```
let test = 'María'

let priority;

testObj.some(item => item.nombre === test ? priority = item.id : priority = 7)
```

This is what it returns:

```
console.log(priority) // 7
```

Why doesn't it return the correct id if the value is found in an object?

Comment: It loops over all items. Unless the last item validates `item.nombre === test`, then `priority` will always be `7`. Why not use `find` instead?

Comment: I'd suggest [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/array/find)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Array.some()` method ends as soon as the callback function returns `true`. Since assigning a truthy value (like 7) is equivalent to `true`, the some ends when `priortiy` is 7. `Array.some()` is used to find if it at least one item matches the criteria, and it's result is a Boolean (true if at least one matches, false if none). Don't use it as a simple loop, or to find a specific item.

Use `Array.find()` instead. If the item is found, destructure it's `id` and assign to `priority`. `Array.find()` returns `null` if it can't find an item. We can use [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) to supply a fallback object with the default value of 7.

```js
const testObj = [
  {id: 1, nombre: "Juan"},
  {id: 2, nombre: "María"},
  {id: 3, nombre: "Pedro"}
];

const test = 'María'

// using destructuring
const { id: priority } = testObj.find(o => o.nombre === test) ?? { id: 7 }
console.log(priority)

// using a ternary
const item = testObj.find(o => o.nombre === test)
const priority2 = item ? item.id : 7
console.log(priority2)

// using optional chaining
const priority3 = testObj.find(o => o.nombre === test)?.id ?? 7;
console.log(priority3)
```

Comment: I had never tried destructuring in this way, although the result works, I will try this form of destructuring

Comment: The desructuring is not the main point. I've added an example with a ternary.

Comment: But in this case item is a boolean, how do you access the value of the object?

Comment: Find returns the item. Some returns a `true` in case an item that matches the criteria exists in the array., Don't use some to find an item, use find.

Answer (score -1):

### The issue

You're setting the value of priority to 7 in the else condition of the ternary operator, which will always execute regardless of whether the value is found or not.

### The solution:

You can modify your code to set the value of priority only when the value is found in the array.

```js
let test = 'María';
let priority = null;
const testObj = [ {id: 1, nombre: "Juan"}, {id: 2, nombre: "María"}, {id: 3, nombre: "Pedro"} ];

testObj.some(item => {
  if (item.nombre === test) {
    priority = item.id;
    return true;
  }
});

console.log(priority); // 2
```

#### Using `for..of` loop:

```
let test = 'María';
let priority = 7;

for (const item of testObj) {
  if (item.nombre === test) {
    priority = item.id;
    break;
  }
}

console.log(priority); // 2
```

#### Using `find()` method:

```
let test = 'María';
let priority = testObj.find(item => item.nombre === test)?.id || 7;

console.log(priority); // 2
```

*Note : using `find()` or a simple `for..of` loop with an early break statement can be a better than using `some`.*

Comment: You are correct that `some()` might not be the most appropriate method for this task, and I've added those two way you mentiened!